# Why are there many similar firewall rules with "RPC-EPMAP" suffix?

Tags: windows-firewall

On Windows8.1, there are many advfirewall rules named `... (RPC-EPMAP)` with:

- same Local port: RPC Endpoint Mapper
- same Program: svchost.exe
- same Service: RPCSS

and I didn't find any difference between these rule definitions.

Why are there those similar rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RPC-EPMAP is the RPC "endpoint mapper", which multiplexes several different MSRPC-based services over a single port. (Similar to HTTP vhosts, I guess.)

Windows Firewall knows more than just TCP ports – AFAIK, it can block and allow individual MSRPC services. So my first guess would be that these rules have hidden parameters which select a specific service.

(The other guess is that the rules *are* duplicates, but needed for Windows Firewall's "simple mode" rule-groups to work.)